# Why does Mathematica provide incosistent convergence conditions?

Tags: summation

```
SumConvergence[(n^(n - 2))/((a^n)*(n!)), n]
```

> Out[1]=$\left| a\right| >e$

```
SumConvergence[(n^(n - 2))/((E^n)*(n!)), n]
```

> Out[2]=True

All right. So, according to `Out[1]`, the series is convergent if and only if the absolute value of variable `a` is greater then the constant `E`.

But, according to `Out[2]`, the series is convergent if `a==E!`, since `Abs[E]` is not greater then `E`, this output seems inconsistent to me...

Where lies the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Mathematica appears to be using different criteria to evaluate the convergence of these two series.  Specifically, we have

```
SumConvergence[(n^(n - 2))/((a^n)*(n!)), n, Method -> "RaabeTest"]
SumConvergence[(n^(n - 2))/((a^n)*(n!)), n, Method -> "RatioTest"]
SumConvergence[(n^(n - 2))/((a^n)*(n!)), n, Method -> "RootTest"]
```

returns

```
(* SumConvergence[(a^-n n^(-2 + n))/n!, n, Method -> "RaabeTest"] *)
(* E/Abs[a] < 1 *)
(* E/Abs[a] < 1 *)
```

but

```
SumConvergence[(n^(n - 2))/((Exp[n])*(n!)), n, Method -> "RaabeTest"]
SumConvergence[(n^(n - 2))/((Exp[n])*(n!)), n, Method -> "RatioTest"]
SumConvergence[(n^(n - 2))/((Exp[n])*(n!)), n, Method -> "RootTest"]
```

returns

```
(* True *) 
(* SumConvergence[(E^-n n^(-2 + n))/n!, n, Method -> "RatioTest"] *)
(* SumConvergence[(E^-n n^(-2 + n))/n!, n, Method -> "RootTest"] *)
```

If you look into the definitions of the [Ratio Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test) and the [Root Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test), it's pretty easy to show that they are inconclusive for the second series.  [Raabe's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#Raabe.27s_test) is an extension of the Root Test, so it succeeds for the second series when the other two methods fail.

My guess is what's happening here is that Mathematica is finding sufficient conditions for convergence rather than necessary conditions.  It tries the Ratio Rest or the Root Test;  if these *can be* conclusive for some values of the parameters, it returns those conditions.  Otherwise, it proceeds to the Raabe Test or some variant thereof.

Mathematica's method does, however, seem to lead us to some patently false results.  For any $a$ such that $|a| = e$,  we have $a = e \cdot e^{i \theta} = e^{1 + i \theta}$ for some $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$, and so $a^n = \exp( n (1 + i \theta))$.  Mathematica can calculate the limits for the Raabe test correctly:

```
c[n_] = (n^(n - 2))/((Exp[n (1 + I θ)])*(n!));
Limit[Abs[c[n]/c[n + 1]], n -> ∞, Assumptions -> θ ∈ Reals]
Limit[n ( Abs[c[n]/c[n + 1]] - 1), n -> ∞, Assumptions -> θ ∈ Reals]

(* 1 *)
(* 5/2 *)
```

On the other hand, we have

```
SumConvergence[c[n], n, Assumptions -> θ ∈ Reals]

(* False *)
```

So there may be a bug here.  That said, I'm not 100% up to date on my Mathematica installation (I'm currently running 10.4.1 on Mac OS) so it's possible that this has been corrected in a later version.